How to create a handle for the PCA9554 io_expander when using it with esp32-S3 on Adafruit Qualia board?
I'm using the Adafruit Qualia board with ESP32-S3. The board uses the PCA9554 io_expander to provide the SPI interface for a 40 pin LCD display (which uses the ST7701 driver). Board schematics which show the ESP32-S3 to LCD connections can be found at

https://learn.adafruit.com/assets/124829

To install the SPI panel, here's the code I've got:
spi_line_config_t line_config = {
.cs_io_type = IO_TYPE_EXPANDER,
.cs_expander_pin = EXAMPLE_LCD_IO_SPI_CS,
.scl_io_type = IO_TYPE_EXPANDER,
.scl_expander_pin = EXAMPLE_LCD_IO_SPI_SCL,
.sda_io_type = IO_TYPE_EXPANDER,
.sda_expander_pin = EXAMPLE_LCD_IO_SPI_SDA,
.io_expander = io_expander, //handle for io_expander
};

What I'm struggling with is how to create this io_expander handle for the PCA9554 expander. I see a library on github for the TCA9554 expander (which is presumably the newer version of PCA9554? I'm not sure). But I don't see a library for the PCA9554 expander. Any idea on how to go about this? Can i use the TCA9554 library for the PCA9554 expander? If yes, what changes do I need to make to the TCA9554 library? I understand one of the key differences between the two is the low supply voltage (1.65 for TCA9554 and 2.5 for PCA9554). Any other differences I should account for?
The ESP example I've got (example_rgb_avoid_tearing.c) uses the esp_lcd_panel_io_additions library, which itself uses the esp_io_expander library  as a dependency. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

why did you use the microelectronics tag? ... are you designing an IC?

@jsotola I'm working with microelectronics and need help with the software part of it. If there's a better tag, please suggest.

then the question is about software, not about microelectronics
